# WCF Streamed endpoint freeze server

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, streaming, wcf-binding

My apologies if this was already answered I can't seem to Google this right to get to my answer.

I have a server and client application set up with WCF communication and works very well. One of my endpoint is using HTTP for streaming purposes (Such as Uploading and Downloading of files). The problem im experiencing is when files are being uploaded and downloaded the Server application hangs (Freezes) as if its running on the main thread. This prevents other client from requesting to the server.

Note: have tried different size files all perform the same symptoms.

All other end points (tcp) on the server is not experiencing the same symptoms they are running multi-threaded and when data is sent and retrieved the server application is still responsive for other clients.

I have tried a couple of things
    1) I have set the ServiceBehaviorAttribute
        a. InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single
        b. ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple
    2) Have tried to set dispatcherSynchronization behavior as well as asynchronousSendEnabled="true"
    3) Increase message size maxReceivedMessageSize

Please can someone assist me on the matter been struggling a while and can't find help.

Server config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="FileTransferServicesBinding" transferMode="Streamed" sendTimeout="20:00:00" receiveTimeout="20:00:00" messageEncoding="Mtom" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"></binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" name="DoorWay.Transfers.FileTransferService">
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="AsyncStreaming" address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FileTransferServicesBinding" contract="DoorWay.Transfers.IFileTransferService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1650/FileTranfer"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AsyncStreaming">
      <dispatcherSynchronization asynchronousSendEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Transfer Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileTransferService
{
    [OperationContract]
    MetaDataRecieve UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request);

    [OperationContract]
    RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request);
}
```

Transfer Class

```
[ServiceBehaviorAttribute(Name = "FileTransferService", InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class FileTransferService : IFileTransferService, IFileDownload
{
    public RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request)
    {
        // get some info about the input file
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Paths.ClientUpdates, request.FileName);

        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);

        // check if exists
        if (!fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            throw new Exception("File does not exist");
        }

        // open stream
        System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

        // return result
        RemoteFileInfo result = new RemoteFileInfo();

        result.FileName = request.FileName;

        result.Length = fileInfo.Length;

        result.FileByteStream = stream;

        return result;
    }

    public MetaDataRecieve UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
    {
        return new MetaDataRecieve() { FileID = this.UploadFileGeneralFile(request) };  
    }

    private long UploadFileGeneralFile(RemoteFileInfo request)
    {
        FileDownloadPresenter presenter = new FileDownloadPresenter(this);

        GeneralAttachmentHelper attachement = new GeneralAttachmentHelper
        {
            FileDataStream = request.FileByteStream,
            Version = -1,
            FileName = request.FileName,
            FileType = request.FileType,
            TableTransfer = request.TableTransfer
        };

        presenter.UploadFile(attachement);

        return this.UploadedFileID;
    }
}
```

Client Config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransferService" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:1650/FileTranfer/mex" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransferService"
            contract="FileTransfer.IFileTransferService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransferService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Test code for freezing I tested

```
    private void DummyTransferDebugTest()
    {
        string file = @"C:\Data\Temp\f629c263-e0ae-4120-b002-f6091bcfa3f5\f629c263-e0ae-4120-b002-f6091bcfa3f5.rar";

        using (FileStream fileRead = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                fileStream.SetLength(fileRead.Length);

                fileRead.Read(fileStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileRead.Length);

                FileTransfer.FileTransferServiceClient transferPresenter = (FileTransfer.FileTransferServiceClient)this.OpenProxy(new FileTransfer.FileTransferServiceClient());

                try
                {
                    System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

                    using (StreamWithProgress streamProgress = new StreamWithProgress(fileStream))
                    {
                        transferPresenter.UploadFile(fileInfo.Name, this.debugFile.ToString(), fileInfo.Length, FileTransfer.TransferTableEnum.RASTERS, streamProgress);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    this.CloseProxy(transferPresenter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If there is anything else I can supply.

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem, the problem was in fact not on how the config was set up or how the streaming end point was setup but how the endpoint was hosted.

I am using a application to host and manage all my service references. When hosting a service reference in this way you need to open the service host in a separate thread as well.

I Created a ThreadManager added it to the base of my application so I can dispose of it.

And started each ServiceHost in its own thread.